# Notation: graphs representing relations between fields

Tags: finite-fields

What are these things called? Can someone explain what the undirected edges represent?

**Example Diagram 1**

Definitions: $F_{4096}$, $F_{64}$, $F_{16}$, $F_8$, $F_4$, and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ are all finite fields.

[image: First example]

**Example Diagram 2**

Definitions:

- $k$ is a field and $k[x]$ is the set of polynomials whose coefficients are in $k$.
- $K$ is a field and $K^{\prime} = k[x]/(f(x))$, where $f(x)\in k[x]$ is 
  irreducible.
- $\phi : k[x] \to K^{\prime}$ is a homomorphism.

I assume the directed edges with the $\phi$ label just represent a homomorphism.

[image: Second example]

Comment: The first looks like a [Hasse Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram). The second looks like a [Commutative Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_diagram).

Comment: Ops. I did not scroll down the page; An answer was already posted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first picture is the [lattice of subfields](https://planetmath.org/LatticeOfFields) of $\mathbb{F}_{2^{12}}$ (or technically, the diagram of it, as Mariano points out). The unlabelled edges represent inclusion as sets (one $\subset$ the other). [See also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Containment).

The second is a [commutative diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_diagram), and $\phi$ a quotient map. The unlabelled edges might represent an evaluation map (replacing instances of the formal variable $x$ with a concrete element $\in k$.)

Comment: (The Hasse diagram of the latttice of subfields, I'd say)

Comment: (Actually, the long vertical line going from the bottom to the top is weird... and kills Hasseness)